# Chaincode for Developers - Hyperledger Fabric Tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm doing the Chaincode Tutorial and I have problems to compile the given chaincode ("Building Chaincode").

If I try to compile the sacc.go with

```
go get -u --tags nopkcs11 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
```

I get

```
package plugin: unrecognized import path "plugin" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

I was thinking about $GOPATH and $GOROOT as problems, so go env gives me

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/name/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0.
This requires Go 1.9 or higher.  Looks like you are using Go 1.6