# Go get not working properly when trying to import shim in Golang

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use go for developing a chaincode for Hyperledger Fabric. Inside chaincode I have to use shim library which can be imported using
 
`import "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"`

I want to use go get to add this package to my project so that I can run and debug the code but when trying use go get with the URL it shows thes errors:
 `package plugin: unrecognized import path "plugin" (import path does not begin with hostname)
package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)`
Is there anybody who can help me fix these errors?

Comment: its better when you show us the whole code.. not just part of it. .also, are you sure you already set your `$GOPATH` correctly..?

Comment: @FendiD Just import part is needed not the whole code. yes I have set it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49464481/6160507 ... you are likely using the wrong version of Go.  Fabric 1.1 requires Go 1.9 and Fabric 1.2 requires Go 1.10.

The `plugin` and `context` packages were not available in earlier versions of Go

Answer (score 1):

On your go get, don't put the full path of the library, instead just put the repository path like this.

> go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric